# Is it possible to query interface statistics bytes by given start time to end time in Juniper Device?

Tags: switch, networking

I can query a interface detail:

```
admin@Juniper-EX# run show interfaces ge-0/0/1 detail
Physical interface: ge-0/0/1, Enabled, Physical link is Down
  Interface index: 131, SNMP ifIndex: 504, Generation: 134
  Link-level type: Ethernet, MTU: 1514, MRU: 0, Speed: Auto, Duplex: Auto,
  BPDU Error: None, MAC-REWRITE Error: None, Loopback: Disabled,
  Source filtering: Disabled, Flow control: Enabled, Auto-negotiation: Enabled,
  Remote fault: Online, Media type: Copper,
  IEEE 802.3az Energy Efficient Ethernet: Disabled
  Device flags   : Present Running Down
  Interface flags: Hardware-Down SNMP-Traps Internal: 0x4000
  Link flags     : None
  CoS queues     : 8 supported, 8 maximum usable queues
  Hold-times     : Up 0 ms, Down 0 ms
  Current address: ec:13:db:25:e3:44, Hardware address: ec:13:db:25:e3:44
  Last flapped   : 2019-06-05 00:45:40 CST (18w5d 17:46 ago)
  Statistics last cleared: Never
  Traffic statistics:
   Input  bytes  :          54149759267                    0 bps
   Output bytes  :           6951255777                    0 bps
   Input  packets:             51845731                    0 pps
   Output packets:             36329994                    0 pps
   IPv6 transit statistics:
    Input  bytes  :                   0
    Output bytes  :                   0
    Input  packets:                   0
    Output packets:                   0
  Egress queues: 8 supported, 4 in use
  Queue counters:       Queued packets  Transmitted packets      Dropped packets
    0                                0             36329994                    0
    1                                0                    0                    0
    5                                0                    0                    0
    7                                0                    0                    0
  Queue number:         Mapped forwarding classes
    0                   best-effort
    1                   assured-forwarding
    5                   expedited-forwarding
    7                   network-control
  Active alarms  : LINK
  Active defects : LINK
  Interface transmit statistics: Disabled

  Logical interface ge-0/0/1.0 (Index 75) (SNMP ifIndex 505) (Generation 141)
    Flags: Device-Down SNMP-Traps 0x4000 Encapsulation: ENET2
    Traffic statistics:
     Input  bytes  :                    0
     Output bytes  :                    0
     Input  packets:                    0
     Output packets:                    0
    Local statistics:
     Input  bytes  :                    0
     Output bytes  :                    0
     Input  packets:                    0
     Output packets:                    0
    Transit statistics:
     Input  bytes  :                    0                    0 bps
     Output bytes  :                    0                    0 bps
     Input  packets:                    0                    0 pps
     Output packets:                    0                    0 pps
    Protocol eth-switch, Generation: 160, Route table: 0
      Flags: None
```

you see there records the traffic statics:

```
Traffic statistics:
   Input  bytes  :          54149759267                    0 bps
   Output bytes  :           6951255777                    0 bps
   Input  packets:             51845731                    0 pps
   Output packets:             36329994                    0 pps
```

Is it possible to query interface statistics bytes from start time to end time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a function a (Juniper) router has, or almost any (enterprise) router for that matter. It can produce general statistics, but for more detailed statistics like information for a given timeframe you should deploy some software specialised for this function.

Unfortunately, software recommendations are off topic here, so if you're looking for specific software to do this you should either ask it on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com or you can try asking in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/general-network-engineering-recommendations).